# where should I put .dockerignore?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

[image]

I have dockerfile in each folder(admin, portal, webpai). and docker-compose file in root only(proxy.yml, services.yml)
where should I put .dockerignore file?
in each folder? or root folder only?

Comment: In each folder, .dockerignore have to be in the same folders as Dockerfile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As each build instruction uses the specified directory (containing the `Dockerfile`) as buildcontext, you need to put the `.dockerignore` into every folder.